# Toggle Drop Down Links Not Working

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, drop-down-menu

I am using the following jquery to create a drop down toggle effect on my side menu (link: http://wp.gattoweb.com/gattotestfour/)

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){
    jQuery('.site-navigation ul ul').hide();
    if(jQuery('.menu-item-has-children').length > 0) {
        jQuery('.menu-item-has-children').click(function(event) {
            jQuery(this).addClass('toggled')
            if(jQuery('.menu-item-has-children').hasClass('toggled'))
            {
                jQuery(this).children('ul').toggle();
            }

            return false;
        });
    }
});
```

This seems to be doing the job for the toggle effect but when I try to click on one of the drop down links, the menu disappears and doesn't go to the linked page.

Answer (score 0):

Try this as a full replacement for your script:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $( '.sub-menu' ).hide();
        $( '.menu-item-has-children' ).click( function() {
          var $this = $( this );
          $this.find('.sub-menu').slideToggle();
          $this.find('.sub-menu').click( function(e) {
            e.stopPropagation();
          });
        });
    });
```

*** Edited ***
Also, I would add he following to CSS and remove the first line of this script:

```
.sub-menu {
  display: none;
}
```

If it's not there, it's fine.

Lastly, there is the issue of design decisions. Do you want "Weddings" to trigger the sub-menu or go to the weddings page? The way it is now, it will load the sub-menu for a split second while the weddings page loads, but your visitor will never really have the opportunity to see your engagement portfolio.

Maybe try using a custom link of "Portfolios" with a link URL in the wordpress admin of "#" and move weddings to a child position under that.

Here's a fiddle of the fix: https://jsfiddle.net/cr46nekL/1/

Comment: does this code replace what I have already? I tried that and it just went back to how it was before. Sorry very inexperienced with any sort of script! And you're totally right about the design element, I suppose Bridal as the trigger and then Weddings and Engagement as the sub-menu thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: @gattocat I edited this so it should work now with what you have.

Comment: added this in and it's gone back to normal. It may be the way I've added it, I'm currently using the plugin Scripts n Styles, could this be the problem?

Comment: When you say normal, what does that mean? Not working at all? The same behavior as you original post?

Comment: apologies, I mean it was the same behaviour as before I added any script. you can see here: http://wp.gattoweb.com/gattotestfour/ I will be more clear!